# Recalculating height of custom UITableViewCell when Delete button appears

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created a UITableViewCell subclass that contains a multiline Label. In the TableViewDelegate, I override `-setEditing:` to recalculate the height of the label with the shortened width when the circular delete widget is visible. This works so far.

However, when this circular widget is tapped and the Delete Button appears, the cell seems to gets relayouted (the Label becomes less wide), but the height of the cells is not recalculated. Setting a breakpoint in`-heightForRowAtIndexPath:` shows that no such event is triggered by tapping the circular widget / the appearing new button. How can I make my tableView recalculate the cells' height in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Try an empty update block like this:

```
[self.myTable beginUpdates];
[self.myTable endUpdates];
```

It updates the row heights (besides other things).

Comment: Yeah, but my question is when to call it for the described situation.

Comment: Maybe it's another problem: When the remove button appears the table view cell and all its subviews are auto-sized according to its autosizing behavior in InterfaceBuilder/Xcode. You can adjust it there to make it stay in place.

Comment: Yes. The label indeed gets resized e.g. when I swipe a line to make the delete button appear. However, the cell it is in does not get resized when this happens and so the text of the label may be pushed down below the border of the cell.

Comment: What I would wish for would be the TableView reevaluating the cell height upon appearance of this button and after the label has autoresized. This doesn't seem to happen. On the other hand, I currently use the crutch of checking for editing=YES in tableView:heightForCellForName and adding a constant. This, however, is bad for localization and changes the height of all cells, even if just a single cell has been swiped and no new elements are added to the other cells. So I'm still looking for a better solution.